# MessageBox.Show early in App startup causes app to terminate

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7, startup, messagebox

As part of my App's startup procedure, it checks data integrity, and if it finds a problem it pops up a message to the user telling them that it might take a while to repair things.

I'm showing the message using MessageBox.Show. Because the data check is done from a worker thread, I'm switching over to the UI thread to make that call, and then setting a ManualResetEvent to tell the worker thread when the user has acknowledged the message.

I kick off the data check/load very early in the app's lifecycle from the constructor in the main Application class, by spinning off a worker thread (using the ThreadPool).

When I run with the debugger, and the message is displayed, the app just waits for input.  When I run without the debugger, the app terminates after displaying the dialog for 10 seconds.

That 10 seconds is a big clue - it tells me that the OS thinks the app took too long to initialize (the OS kills apps that take too long to start up).

I think that my MessageBox.Show is blocking the UI thread before the App.RootFrameNavigating has a chance to be invoked.

My questions:

- Does my diagnosis sound right?
- I'd prefer to kick off my data load early, because it is almost entirely IO, except for this Message Box, and the sooner I can get my Model loaded, the better, but do you normally delay your data load until later in the app lifecycle?
- Any other ideas/suggestions?  I can't guarantee which page will be the start page, because the app could be resuming to any page.  I'm also thinking of having the MessageBox.Show delay itself until the app has initialized, perhaps polling away for a flag set by App.RootFrameNavigating - does that make sense?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, the solution I've come up with is to still kick off the data load in a worker-thread from the Application's constructor, but in my PhoneService's class ShowDialog method that I invoke to invoke MessageBox.Show, I check to see if the initial navigation has occurred:

```
private readonly ManualResetEvent _appInitialized = new ManualResetEvent(false);

public void AppInitialized()
{
    _appInitialized.Set();
}


public void ShowDialog(string caption, string text, Action<MessageBoxResult> callback, MessageBoxButton button = MessageBoxButton.OKCancel)
{
    _appInitialized.WaitOne();
    DispatcherHelper.CheckBeginInvokeOnUI(() =>
    {
        var result = MessageBox.Show(text, caption, button);

        if (callback != null)
        {
            callback(result);
        }
    });
}
```

Then in my Application class:

```
private bool _firstNavigate = true;
private void RootFrameNavigating(object sender, NavigatingCancelEventArgs e)
{
    if (_firstNavigate)
    {
        _firstNavigate = false;
        var navigationService = (NavigationService) sender;
        navigationService.Navigated += NavigationServiceNavigated;
    }
         ....


private void NavigationServiceNavigated(object sender, NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    var navigationService = (NavigationService)sender;
    navigationService.Navigated -= NavigationServiceNavigated;
    PhoneServices.Current.AppInitialized();
}
```

Anyone see any issues with this approach?  Anyone come up with a better way?

Comment: Looks like this should work fine. If starting an app from scratch I'd probably do it the other way round. I'd use an Mvvm-light message from the background worker to to the UI layer rather than a semaphore. That would avoid changes in the Application class too.

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is a result of kicking off the worker thread in the Application constructor.  You should use the appropriate life-cycle event, in this case: [PhoneApplicationService.Activated Event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.phone.shell.phoneapplicationservice.activated%28v=VS.92%29.aspx)

Comment: I'm not sure that there is intrinsically an issue with launching my data-load so early, it's just that it is blocking the UI thread too early ... Also, activated isn't invoked if the app is started from it's tile - it is only invoked "when the application is being made active after previously being put into a dormant state or tombstoned".

Comment: I initially answered saying you should use PhoneApplicatinService.Launching, but noticed the documentation says specifically not to load data during this event.  You can always check to see if the data has already been loaded from the Activated event for the same effect, which sounds like the ideal solution.  The issue likely stems from the fact that you are doing things in the constructor that you shouldn't -- You are trying to load data for an application that hasn't even finished constructing.  I suggest you at least give it a shot to rule out the possibility.

Comment: I think that loading data from Isolated Storage can be done in parallel with the rest of the application startup, provided it doesn't block the UI thread.  If not, why not?

Comment: Application start-up is highly facilitated by the OS.  I certainly couldn't tell you the specific reason why you couldn't, but it could be a variety of things.  The documentation says very specifically when data should and should not be loaded, and it definitely should not be done in the constructor.  So, you really have two options:  Do something the documentation tells you not to, and wonder why your application crashes, or do as the documentation tells you, and likely avoid a crash.

Comment: I'm not loading the data in the constructor, I'm kicking off a worker thread there.

Comment: Just to be clear, which event do you think I should be using, given my comment above re Activated not being invoked on normal startup?

Comment: PhoneApplicationService.Launching is the event that you likely want, so long as you aren't loading data in the same thread.  I imagine this is where you'd want to kick off the worker thread.

Comment: I can't see how that's going to make any difference. The key is to get the app running in 10s before the OS terminates it.

Comment: The time from when the constructor fires to the time the Launching and Activating event fires is a matter of milliseconds.  This is a classic case of premature optimization with no apparent justification.

Comment: In this case calling it from Launching will make no difference - its the fact that I am blocking the UI thread before the app is fully initialized that is the issue.